# how to unregister availability callback in CameraManager in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

i have used CameraManager  to check if camera is on or off in android.
And i have successfully got it.But now I need to unregister it.i have referred https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#registerAvailabilityCallback(android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback,android.os.Handler) 
  but i dont know how to implement it.
could anyone please help?? below is my code snippet for registering availability manager

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        manager.registerAvailabilityCallback(new CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraAvailable(String cameraId) {
                super.onCameraAvailable(cameraId);
                //Do your work
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "camera off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCameraUnavailable(String cameraId) {
                super.onCameraUnavailable(cameraId);
                //Do your work
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "camera on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, yourHandler);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar method to unregister the same callback - `CameraManager.unregisterAvailabilityCallback()`.

You will need to keep the callback's reference and pass the same while registering as well as unregistering.

Your code will look something like:

```
private CameraManager mCameraManager;
private Object mCameraCallback;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mCameraManager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mCameraCallback = new CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraAvailable(String cameraId) {
                super.onCameraAvailable(cameraId);
                //Do your work
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "camera off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCameraUnavailable(String cameraId) {
                super.onCameraUnavailable(cameraId);
                //Do your work
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "camera on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        mCameraManager.registerAvailabilityCallback((CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback) mCameraCallback, yourHandler);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mCameraManager.unregisterAvailabilityCallback((CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback) mCameraCallback)
    }
}
```

Comment: i came across this.but i dont know what arguments should i pass according to my code.

Comment: Thanks,its a good one.but it dnt work.its same as before.it is continuously checking if camera is on or off.but after sometime i need to stop doing that check.is unregistering it  not the correct way then?

Comment: Unregistering is the perfect way. You might want to do it somewhere other than `onDestroy()`? What problem are you facing after you implemented this?

Comment: its the same as before without impementing this.i.e the service is running infinitely.

Comment: You might want to stop the service explicilty then.

Comment: Sorry for bringing up this old post but what is `yourHandler` in this?

Comment: It is an instance of `Handler` class. Reference:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler?hl=en